# How do I use GoogleSignIn on iOS without coupling with the View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I've created a GoogleLoginManager which is init with a VC that will present the GoogleSignIn login:

```
- (instancetype)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
        _vc = viewController;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've implemented the methods as described in step 3. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in as the above class isn't a subclass of a VC. The Google Login is presented, but after logging in the delegate methods aren't triggered?

Comment: You most certainly want the `uiDelegate` to be set to the `viewController`.

Comment: Hmm, step 3. indicates that avoiding this is possible

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Did you check for typos in the names of your three methods? Have you correctly added the protocol to your class?

Comment: Of course, I suppose there's some other strong reference to your class instance so that it's still in memory when `GIDSignIn` needs it? (as `uiDelegate` and `delegate` are `weak` references)

Comment: My GoogleManager looks like this: http://pastebin.com/AWNK7VX5 and I've added <GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate> so it conforms to the protocols. I'm then instantiating with my login VC.

Comment: The code on your link does not include any of the three methods? Also the fact that you instantiate it does not mean you keep a reference to it...

Comment: You're ace! I created a @property to store the login manager as a strong reference and it's working perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was no strong reference to this object (both `uiDelegate` and `delegate` are `weak`, so they're not enough to keep the object in memory if no strong reference exists).

Just make sure you have a (strong, which is the default) property or instance variable that points to this object as long as it is needed.